# How to handle json data using jax-rs classes

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs

What is the best approach to accept json data using jax-rs(resteasy) classes.
**My json data will come in the following format.**

> ```
> {
>   "question": "Question???",
>   "options":[
>                {"option": "option1"},
>                {"option": "option2"},
>                {"option": "option2"},
>                {"option": "option2"}
>             ],
>   "answer": "answer" 
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSON parser such as Jackson.